# Regex with perl one liner

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following:

```
XXUM_7_mauve_999119_ser_11.255255

UXUM_566_mauve_999119_ser_11.255255

IXUM_23_mauve_999119_ser_11.255255
```

and my attempt, which did not work, at a perl one liner to extract the first digit is as follows;

```
perl -pi -e "s/\S+_(\.+)_.+/Number$1/g" *.txt
```

I expected the following results:

```
Number 007
Number 566
Number 023
```

pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the `-n` option instead of the `-p` option and do the printing and formatting in the code:

```
  perl -i~ -ne 'if (($num) = /[0-9]+/g) {
                    printf "Number %03d\n", $num;
                } else {
                    print
                }' *.txt
```

Comment: Thanks guys. These solutions work,but they also overwrite texts which do not have this pattern

Comment: @RobJohn: The `else` branch should keep the non-matching lines.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that this regex pattern `/\S+_(\.+)_.+/` looks for a sequence of one or more literal dots `.` surrounded by underscores, so something like `_..._` would match, but such a sequence doesn't exist in your file. I think you didn't mean to escape the dot. But even then, because the `\S+` is greedy, it would find and capture the *last* field delimited by underscores, and so would capture `ser` from all three lines. Perhaps you meant to write `\d+` instead of `\.+`, which is pretty much what I have written below.

This will do as you ask. It looks for the *first* occurrence of an underscore that is followed by a number of decimal digits, and uses `printf` to format the number as three digits.

You can add the `-i` qualifier, but I suggest you test it as it is first to save overwriting your data with erroneous results. Of course you could redirect the output to another file if you wished.

```
perl -ne'/_(\d+)/ and printf "Number %03d\n", $1' myfile
```

**output**

```
Number 007
Number 566
Number 023
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat > /tmp/test
XXUM_7_mauve_999119_ser_11.255255
UXUM_566_mauve_999119_ser_11.255255
IXUM_23_mauve_999119_ser_11.255255

perl -i -ne 'if ($_=~/^\w+\_(\d+)\_mauve/g) { printf "Number %03d\n", $1; }' /tmp/test

cat /tmp/test 
Number 007
Number 566
Number 023
```

Comment: Thanks @piaf for your time and effort